# Joomla 3 pages not showing in live mode

Tags: joomla

I am new to Joomla and PHP, I hope someone can help please. I have checked the forum, but have not found anything to help me for the Joomla version I have.

**System Details**

- Joomla: 3.2.0 Stable
- PHP: 5.4.14
- Server: Apache

I have worked through setting up a Joomla site and had the site working while the **Site offline mode** was switched on.

I reached the point to want to test the site live and switched the **site live back on** and now I am getting **404 errors** when I want to access the site.

I went back through the permissions and **ensured everything is set to public** for the articles etc. The language files are set to All.

Again, I am sure this is probably a quick and easy fix, (hoping) or otherwise I will need to rebuild the site; which I want to try to avoid if possible.

Hoping someone can help me as soon as possible, if you have any suggestions.

Comment: What does the 404 page look like? Is it the Joomla 404 page, or your web server 404 page? Check the permissions for your menu and menu items in your Menu Manager, as well as the menu module in your Module Manager.

Comment: Hi Mark it is the Joomla 404 page and I have checked the menu and menu items. Since posting this, three of the menu links are now working and I can access those pages content. However, I am still having the problem with four other pages. Which I cannot figure out what is happening... Access is the same as the pages that are showing, the menu permissions are correct.... Any other thoughts? appreciate your time.. Regards Jennifer

Comment: Maybe try clearing your Joomla and browser caches?

If you ask on the joomla forums, you'll usually get people who'll be willing to log into your website and try and fix it for you. Worth a try if the alternative is to trash your site and rebuild from scratch.

Comment: Thanks Mark, yeah already tried the cache cleaning as one of the first options.... appreciate your help. Anyway, will keep searching for an answer.. before the dreaded rebuild takes place.. :) cheers again Regards Jennifer

Comment: What kind of menu link is your default page?
also what happens if you enter something like index.php?option=com_users&view=login ... white screen is usually due to extternal plugins ..rebuilding will not solve that problem

Comment: Hi Elin, default page is a component, so that is coming up whn logged in or not. The issue pages are articles, that are there when logged in but cannot be found (404 error) when you try to view as public. As I said, all permissions are correct, and I am sure it is something simple... but because other pages are showing, I just cannot figure out why these ones aren't. I tried adding a new article to the menu, and again, it is working in login mode, but not in publiic view. ussing: index.php?option=com_users&view=login that you asked about shows the login page. Thanks 4 ur time, cheers Jennifer

Comment: Thanks Mark and Elin for your time, I have found the issue; I had not published the categories and so that stops the pages appearing in public mode. again thaks for taking the time to help. It was greatly appreciated. Regards

Comment: @Jennifer I have the same problem. And I am able to fix this reading your comment. Thankx :)

Answer (score 0):

there are a quick option to resolve it using create a new menu item and make defualt it.
Then check.

Comment: there must already be a default menu item, else the site wouldn't have worked in the first place

Comment: i have suggest to changed the default menu.